# OOM error while converting Map keySet to String array - Android

Tags: java, android, performance, hashmap, out-of-memory

I have the below util class

```
class Util {
  private static Map<String, String> params;

  public static String getSignedUrl(Context context) {
    params= null; // reset previous instance
    params= new HashMap<>();
    ...
    addDefaultParams();
    addCustomParams();
    String signedUrl = getSignedUrl();
    ....
    return signedUrl;
  }

  private static String getSignedUrl() {
     String[] keyArray = params.keySet().toArray(new String[0]); // OOM error here!
     .....
     return signedUrl;
  } 

  private static void addDefaultParams() {
    //add some default params
    params.add(key, value);
  }

  private static void addCustomParams() {
    //add some custom params
    params.add(key, value);
  }

}
```

From the firebase stack trace below line is causing OutOfMemoryError

```
String[] keyArray = params.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Is it because `params` is a static field?. But I am resetting the previous instance of `params` so I am not sure why this is causing OOM issue.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 186909524 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 262MB until OOM
java.lang.reflect.Array.createObjectArray (Array.java)
java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray (AbstractCollection.java:198)
.......
.......
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:760)
```

Comment: Could you show us the error message?

Comment: post error stack here.

Comment: cannot add the entire stack trace but added the part of it @deHaar

Comment: If you use more than 1 thread the code & data will not be thread-safe.

Comment: @JoopEggen but does it cause OOM ?

Comment: I honestly doubt it inthis case. But if `getSignedUrl(Context)` is called recursively the OOM would be explained, say called in addCustomParameters.

Comment: @JoopEggen u mean like a recursive call ?

Comment: @ik024 yes, indirectly

Comment: @JoopEggen i had the same feeling - turns out my app was calling the api when ever device is reconnect to network. I have limited that - have released a new version. Monitoring my firebase analytics